# How to upgrade a particular package dependencies only?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

Let's say I have a package `A` which has `Depends: B (>= 1.0.0)` in its `control` file.

The `B` was installed as an `A` dependency some time ago with `1.0.0` version.

Now `B` was updated in the repository to the `1.0.42` version and I'd like to `upgrade` it.

What I don't like to do: `apt-get install B` since it will mark `B` as "manually installed" (not sure how to name it correctly) package and it won't be removed with `autoremove` if I decide to stop using `A` ever.

So is there an analogue of `apt-get upgrade` that only upgrades a particular package and its dependencies (probably recursive, it doesn't matter in my case since `B` doesn't depend on anything else) only?

PS: I'm asking about currently available LTS versions. So 10.04 and 12.04

Comment: `apt-get install --only-upgrade` *might* pass muster.. but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Seth: Hm, I don't see such an option in man

Comment: Which Ubuntu version? In 13.04 at least, don't remember for earlier versions, using `apt-get install B` to upgrade the package should not mark it as manually installed. As long as there is a new version for it in the repo after you `apt-get update`

Comment: @Dan: LTS ones, sorry I didn't mention that originally

Comment: @Dan: just checked it - installing a package explicitly with `apt-get install` **does* mark a package as installed manually. Checked it in 12.04 using `apt-mark showauto`. It can be fixed with `apt-mark` though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, if there won't be another answer - here is one way of doing that:

Just install it with `apt-get install B` explicitly, then mark it as auto installed using `apt-mark markauto B`

Answer (score 2):

*Being specific to your question, I'd do:*

- `apt-get update` to resynchronize the package index files from their sources.
- `apt-get install B` will install the latest version.
- `apt-mark auto B` to mark it *automatically installed*

To upgrade a particular package:

- `apt-get update`
- `apt-get install <package_name>` this installs the updated package... there... the package is upgraded unlike `apt-get upgrade` which would upgrade all upgradable packages.

In case you want particular version of a package you'd do:

- `apt-get <package_name>=<verson>` or `apt-get -t <version> <package_name>`

With `apt-get -t <version> <package_name>`, you could specify target-release as -t '2.1*', -t unstable or -t sid.

If you want a list of available versions:

- `apt-cache showpkg <package_name>`

Comment: I'm not sure you understand the question correctly.

Comment: If you're concerned with removing orphaned dependencies/packages you might want to try debfoster, gtkorphan in case you haven't already.